# Angular Material tables doesnt display data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

I have deployed my Angular Application in a server. After many tests, I found that Angular Material table doesn't display any data, while you cann see data in logs.

I have this probleme just in production, everything works great in developpement.

The data will be sent from a database.

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt8Ks.png)

As you can clearly see, there is data but not displayed.

**My HTML file:**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
              <ng-container matColumnDef="CODE">
                <th id ="n" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Code</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.CODE}}</td>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container matColumnDef="NAME">
                <th id="typeLien" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nom</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.NAME}}</td>
              </ng-container>
              <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
              <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
            </table>
```

**My TS file:**

```
this.communicationService.getArticles().toPromise().then(allArticles=> {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(allArticles);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign `dataSource.data`. Try this:

```
this.communicationService.getArticles().toPromise().then(allArticles=> {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(allArticles);
      this.dataSource.data = allArticles;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reponse, but my question is, why it worked properly in dev, while in production no?

Comment: Yes. I haven't changed anything but deploying my app

Answer (score 0):

```
this.communicationService.getArticles().toPromise().then(allArticles => {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(allArticles);
    /*enter code here*/
    this.datasource.data = allArticles
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
});
```

Please change your Ts side like this.

Comment: Still doesn't work, it seems like I need to change the page or the size page the get the elements

Answer (score 0):

Its because table is rendering before response from service.Add *ngIf condition before rendering.

```
<table *ngIf="dataSource" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
              <ng-container matColumnDef="CODE">
                <th id ="n" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Code</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.CODE}}</td>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container matColumnDef="NAME">
                <th id="typeLien" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nom</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.NAME}}</td>
              </ng-container>
              <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
              <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, it seems like I need to change the page or the size page the get the elements